# How to delete duplicate rows from mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

1. How to delete duplicate rows or documents in mongo?
     How to
   integrate with Python???

Example:

```
> db.US_Dollar.createIndex({currencies:1},{unique:1, dropDups:1})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: shridhar.US_Dollar index: currencies_1 dup key: { : \"British Pound\" }",
        "code" : 11000,
        "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
> db.US_Dollar.createIndex({bid:1},{unique:1, dropDups:1})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: shridhar.US_Dollar index: bid_1 dup key: { : 0.9248 }",
        "code" : 11000,
        "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
> db.US_Dollar.createIndex({sdk:1},{unique:1, dropDups:1})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: shridhar.US_Dollar index: sdk_1 dup key: { : null }",
        "code" : 11000,
        "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
> db.US_Dollar.createIndex({ask:1},{unique:1, dropDups:1})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: shridhar.US_Dollar index: ask_1 dup key: { : 0.9204 }",
        "code" : 11000,
        "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
```

Comment: I am getting error like above

Comment: Read the linked duplicate instead of the incorrect answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on whatever your uniqueness criterion is & set `dropDups` to `true`

```
db.collection.createIndex({...}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

Check out how to do this with PyMongo: [How to delete duplicate rows from mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55453503/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-from-mongodb)